# Excel: Hours/Minutes to Decimal Values

Tags: vba, excel

Before anything else, I'm using Excel 2010.

I'm trying to simplify a process to get information from a report I run that generates the time in seconds. I need decimal time instead of hours and so far this is the only solution I could come up with.Example:

A1 contains the time in seconds.

```
1843 (seconds)
```

B1 contains the formula to conver the seconds into hours

```
=B1/(1440*60) This gives me 0:30:43
```

Then I have to calculate how much time over 0:30:00 is left, which is what I need.

```
=IF(B1<$H$1,"ON TIME",SUM(B1-$H$1))
```

This formula I have it placed in C2, H1 contains the time limit 0:30:00 and the cell is formatted as [h]:mm:ss. which I use to calculate what's the time over the limit.

Once I have the time over the limit, in this case 0:00:43 seconds, I have to conver this to decimals to get what I really need out of all this and for that I use the following formula.

```
=C2*60*24
```

This formula (placed in R1) gives me the result 0.72 but I have to copy this result and paste it on another cell and when I do that and paste the values, I get this. 0.71666666666667. even if the cell is formatted as number with 2 decimal places. it only affects what I see in the cell, not the actual value that's in the cell.

Now, to fix that and get the right number. I have another formula place in S1 to give me the right number which after copied and pasted as value, I get the actual value I need.

```
=TRUNC(R1,2)
```

This gives me 0.71 and if I copy and paste what I get from that formula and paste it as value, I get to keep 0.71.

Is there any way to shortten this process thru VBA or any other formula altenatives?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the answer in decimal `minutes` as shown then it's easier to convert everything to a decimal number representing `minutes`, e.g. divide A1 by 60 and multiply H1 by 1440, so assuming the seconds value in A1 is always `greater` than the equivalent value in H1 you can use this single formula

`=FLOOR(A1/60-$H$1*1440,0.01)`

format as number with 2 decimal places and you get 0.71 as required

If you want to incorporate the "On time" part of your IF function use this version

`=IF(A1/60>$H$1*1440,FLOOR(A1/60-$H$1*1440,0.01),"ON TIME")`

If H1 doesn't change you can replace `$H$1*1440` in the formula with the decimal minutes, e.g. `30`

Comment: Thank you. The first formula worked well and gave me the right number but the second one gives me a negative number unless I format the cell as number with a positive-negative number.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I entered a wrong statement in the formula, corrected and now it's working. Thank you so much, this eases and minimizes the size of my report by a whole lot.